# GIT push fails with message "error: failed to push some refs to" and "error: git-remote-https died of signal 13"

Tags: linux, git, github

I have been using cvs2git tool to migrate several projects from cvs to github repository. Most of the projects succeeded but 3 of them failed with the below message when I am running:

> [root@nj09mhe5384 tdc-misc]# git push --all origin Counting objects:
>   8586, done. Delta compression using up to 2 threads. Compressing
>   objects: 100% (3015/3015), done. fatal: The remote end hung up
>   unexpectedly error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/kingshuk-chakraborty/tdc-misc2.git' error:
>   git-remote-https died of signal 13

I tried to run

```
GIT_TRANSPORT_HELPER_DEBUG=1 git push --all origin to get a clue about it.
```

I got the below message

> Debug: Remote helper: Waiting... Counting objects: 8586, done. Delta
>   compression using up to 2 threads. Compressing objects: 100%
>   (3015/3015), done. Debug: Remote helper quit.8/8586) fatal: The remote
>   end hung up unexpectedly error: failed to push some refs to
>   'https://github.com/kingshuk-chakraborty/tdc-misc2.git' Debug:
>   Disconnecting. error: git-remote-https died of signal 13

Then I ran with `strace -f` and in log found broken pipe error.

> [pid 13473] poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}], 1, 1000) = 1 ([{fd=3,
>   revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}]) [pid 13473] poll([{fd=3, events=POLLOUT}],
>   1, 0) = 1 ([{fd=3, revents=POLLERR|POLLHUP}]) [pid 13473] write(3,
>   "\25\3\1\0
>   &(\351\343\305g\16Z4\27t\"\25\334\333U\376\35\317\271\30B\2343\371\364\240"...,
>   37) = -1 EPIPE (Broken pipe) [pid 13473] --- SIGPIPE (Broken pipe) @ 0
>   (0) --- Process 13473 detached

Please note that the repositories don't have any file which is larger than 50mb.  What's going wrong?

Comment: I think I once stumbled upon something like that when trying to migrate from svn to git. It worked when I ran the command directly on our svn server. After completion, I copied (or cloned?) the git repository to my machine.

Comment: Does the same error happen if you push over ssh instead of https?

Comment: I am still getting the same error. Error is as below.[root@nj09mhe5384 tdc-misc]# git push --all origin
 Warning: Permanently added the RSA host key for IP address '192.30.252.128' to the list of known hosts.
 Counting objects: 8586, done.
 Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
 Compressing objects: 100% (3015/3015), done.
 remote: error: object c56c016b1c0103fb2dd7e992db7f7b857c033d93:contains '.git'
 remote: fatal: Error in object
 error: pack-objects died of signal 13
 error: failed to push some refs to 'git@github.com:kingshuk-chakraborty/tdc-misc2.git'